# laravel fetch relationship data as separate records with paginations

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Post and Comment are models.
Post has hasMany relationship to Comment.

if  post1 has one comment (c1), i want fetch them as two records
one for parent model and one for relationship record
so it would show something like this.

```
post_id comment_id  name    owner_name  comment
1       null        p1      owner1      null    //from parent model
1       1           p1      owner1      c1      //from relationship
```

```
posts
====

post_id     name    owner_name
1           p1      owner1
2           p2      owner2
3           p3      owner3
4           p4      owner4


comments
========

comment_id  comment     post_id
1           c1          1   
2           c2          1
3           c3          2


Expected results
================
post_id comment_id  name    owner_name  comment
1       null        p1      owner1      null
1       1           p1      owner1      c1
1       2           p1      owner1      c2
2       null        p2      owner2      null
2       3           p2      owner2      c3
3       null        p3      owner3      null
4       null        p4      owner4      null
```

Comment: `$posts = Post::with('comments')->get()` where is the issue ?

Comment: this return a nested json. i want separate objects.

Comment: then run them seperatly. `$posts = Post::get();` & `$comments = Comment::get();`

Comment: so how do you suggest for paginations? i want these records as pagination collection